# Pass a parameters to Click-once Setup.exe file

Tags: asp.net, .net, deployment, clickonce

I have a .net windows application, and i to run this application on client machine through asp.net web page.

I have used the Click-once technique which is publish the windows application in a setup package and place it as an IIS Application.

Now i want to pass a parameters to the windows application.

to pass parameters the click once app i am using a URL to .application and pass parameters as query string parameters file, but the problem here is the .application file doesn't setup the prerequisites first, i.e if the client machine doesn't have .NET framework installed the application will return error !!.

can anyone tell me how to pass a parameters to click-once application and check for prerequisites first.

also if there's another technique rather than click-once please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties window of your windows application project, look for publish tab. You can set the prerequisites in this tab.

Here is also the detailed instructions from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

[image]

Comment: this is fine but this prerequisites is not installed automatically when you access the application through a URL to the .application file